# How to unit test a method which returns token from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, nunit, access-token

I have a method in my project which returns token from Azure. Im writing unit test for that using nUnit.

This line in my test code is giving exception.

```
mockConfidentialClientApp.Setup(app => app.AcquireTokenForClient(It.IsAny<string[]>()).ExecuteAsync()).Returns(
            Task<AuthenticationResult>.Run(() => new AuthenticationResult("testAccessToken", true, null, DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now, string.Empty, null, null, null, Guid.Empty)));
```

I'm getting this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....ExecuteAsync()
> Non-overridable members (here: BaseAbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Can someone help fix this?

Comment: you cannot mock a method chain like `app.AcquireTokenForClient(...).ExecuteAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

The `app.AcquireTokenForClient(It.IsAny<string[]>())` method returns `AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder`. Thus, try to mock its `AcquireTokenForClientParameterBuilder.ExecuteAsync()`.